# cordova - bundle extra binary file to the app root

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins

when building a project, HOW do i instruct cordova to add a file.bin to the resulted APK, so that after installing the apk the file will be available in this path: **/data/data/com.myapp/file.bin**

file.bin is a ( Cross-compiled Android binary file ) from the https://github.com/aria2/aria2 project, it is a command line tool downloader that run on android.

i installed plugin: org.apache.cordova.shell-exec
so that i can "**chmod 755 /data/data/com.myapp/file.bin**" and call this binary file from my js code.

i tried adding to config.xml:
**`<resource-file src="file.bin" target="app/src/main/file.bin" />`** but this did not work, it was not add to the final .APK, although it was copied to app/src/main/file.bin.

Comment: you can add this file inside your assets folder just like your images and try accessing it from there.